# How to combine into a list previously defined objects based on string matching (in the name)?

Tags: r

I am trying to merge into a list a number or vectors:

```
 vector1<- c(0:9)
 vector2<- c(10:19)
 vector3<- c(20:29)
 vector4<- c(30:39)
```

Ideally I would like to be able to select from all the objects defined in the enviorment the ones that the name matches `vector`.
I was thinking something on these lines but I do not know how to continue:

```
 library(stringr)
 files<-ls()
 str_subset(files, "vector")
```

I get a list of the correct names, however this vector is character. I would need to get a list containing `vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4`
Suggestions?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a list.  `.GlobalEnv` is shown explicitly but if the environment of interest is that then it can be omitted since that is the default, i.e. it would be good enough to write `mget(ls(pattern = "^vector"))` .  If you want to ensure that you only get names that are of the form `vector` followed by digits then use `^vector\\d+$` as the regular expression.

```
vector1 <- vector2 <- vector3 <- 1:4

mget(ls(pattern = "^vector", envir = .GlobalEnv), .GlobalEnv)
```

giving this list:

```
$`vector1`
[1] 1 2 3 4

$vector2
[1] 1 2 3 4

$vector3
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option to use `parse`, `eval`, and `lapply`. You can use `str_subset` instead of `grep` if you want.

```
files <- ls()

vecs <- grep("vector", files, value = TRUE)

lapply(vecs, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

Comment: This is not the preferred way. Use `mget` (see Gabor's answer).